# Erro Full authentication is required to access this resource

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot

Olá,
Eu tenho um backend feito com Spring e eu gero um arquivo .jar e 'subo' ele via VSCode para o front feito em Angular. 
Quando eu tento acessar a minha página (tudo está localhost), eu recebo esse retorno:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): HttpErrorResponse: {"headers":{"normalizedNames":{},"lazyUpdate":null},"status":401,"statusText":"OK","url":"http://localhost:8080/lancamento?resumo","ok":false,"name":"HttpErrorResponse","message":"Http failure response for http://localhost:8080/lancamento?resumo: 401 OK","error":{"timestamp":"2019-01-10","status":401,"error":"Unauthorized","message":"Full authentication is required to access this resource","path":"/lancamento"}}
```

Meu código no Angular está dessa forma:

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient) { } 

pesquisar(): Promise<any> {
const headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.append('Authorization', 'Basic YWRtaW5AYWxnYW1vbmV5LmNvbTphZG1pbg==');
return this.http.get(`${this.lancamentoUrl}?resumo`, { headers}).toPromise()
     .then(response => {
      console.log(response);
 });
```

}

O meu código CORS está assim:

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp, FilterChain chain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {

    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) resp;

    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", ApiProperty.getOriginPermitida());
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, DELETE, PUT, OPTIONS");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Authorization, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Origin,Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");

    // response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);

    //

    if ("OPTIONS".equals(request.getMethod())) {
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
    } else {
        chain.doFilter(req, resp);
    }

}
```

O meu originPermitida está assim:

```
private String originPermitida = "*";
```

O meu código HttpSecurity está assim:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll()
        .and()
        .httpBasic()
        .and()
        .antMatcher("/**")
        .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        .and()
        .csrf().disable();
}
```

No Postman, abre que é uma beleza, o erro acontece quando eu abro a página via browse.

Onde eu estou errando? Poderiam me dar um norte?

Obrigado!

Comment: Qual o tipo de segurança está utilizando, Http Basic, OAuth ?

Comment: Estou usando Basic mesmo.

Comment: Consegui realizar um debug agora e chequei que no momento que é feito o if do OPTIONS no CORS (Esse pedaço aqui: if ("OPTIONS".equals(request.getMethod()))), o retorno disso tá vindo como GET. Pelo que eu peguei de explicação, o OPTIONS seria uma 'pergunta ao browse' se pode enviar algumas coisas, antes mesmo de enviar. Estaria pulando alguma etapa ? O mais estranho é que via Postman não dá o problema.

Comment: Não consegui evoluir nesse problema. @ViktorHugo consegue ajudar?

Answer (score 0):

Olá, 
Para quem tiver o mesmo problema que eu, encontrei a seguinte solução:

Na construção do meu Header eu alterei para isso:

```
pesquisar() {
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type':  'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Basic YWRtaW5AYWxnYW1vbmV5LmNvbTphZG1pbg=='
  })
};

return this.http.get(`${this.lancamentoUrl}?resumo`, httpOptions )
                .subscribe((data) => {console.log(data); } );
```

}

Tive que tirar o promise e a chamada ficou mais simples:

```
 pesquisar() {
this.lancamentoService.pesquisar();
```

}

Eu tive um apoio sobre isso me explicando que houve alteração na versão do Angular em todo esse 'módulo' do HTTP. Eu não havia mencionado, estou utilizando a versão 7.1.3 do Angular. 
Talvez da forma como estava antes funciona para versão 4, mas, para essa nova versão não funcionou.

Answer (score 0):

return this.http.get(`${this.lancamentoUrl}?resumo`, httpOptions )
                .subscribe((data) => {console.log(data); } );

Onde vc colocou esse comando ?

Answer (score 0):

Complementando ao que o Victor falou, eu consegui acessar os métodos configurando o "CrossOrigin"

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200") //CONFIGURACAO DO CROSS
@GetMapping
public Page<Lancamento> pesquisar(LancamentoFilter lancamentoFilter, Pageable pageable){
    return lancamentoRepository.filtrar(lancamentoFilter, pageable);
}
```